# Nexus Repository configuration(readonly) privileges

Tags: roles, nexus

How to see the repository configuration in readonly mode in Nexus console ?

Comment: Can you be more precise?

Comment: It depends on privileges and roles your user has been assigned in Nexus.
But with existing privileges in Nexus you can't have read only view to independent repository configurations. You may need UI:Repository Administration